# issues Installing pnp/generator

Tags: spfx, error, office-dev-pnp, error-handling, npm

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to install PnP/generator. Do anyone know how I can get passed this issue. I have the SharePoint generator installed already. [image: Stating that I need to upgrade to v2.x.x]